# Docker variables scope

Tags: docker

I want to know where can I see the variables I have defined. For example, I have three files:

```
.env 
BLA=1

docker-compose.xml
IS_ONE=${BLA}

Dockerfile
RUN echo "$BLA" >> file.txt
```

I want to know the relation, for example:

Do I need the variable defined in all files? or there a relation like

- docker-compose.xml can only see .evn variables?
- Dockerfile can only see docker-compose.xml variables?

And, where do I need to declare a variable to use in a bash script automatically triggered in Dockerfile (if it's possible), or use later in the console of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of examples here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

If you need to customize docker-compose itself then .env file is used.
For example, I want to include build id in my container name, my .env file would have

`BUILD_ID=20`

and docker-compose.yml would have

`containername: "foo-${BUILD_ID}"`

If I want to pass environment vars into container when it runs, I use

`environment:
  - FOO_VAR=bar`

If I want to pass in multiple environment vars into container, 
docker-compose.yml would have

`env_file: my_container_env`

is the easy way if the values of the FOO_VAR are going to be dynamically generated.

Whether to use set env values in docker-compose directly or use file depends on:

1. Are the values dynamic? If yes, use file and populate correct values
   in the file with some script (like jenkins could set my BUILD_ID in
   my .env file)
2. Are they 'secret'? If yes, use file and don't checkin the .env or my_container_env file into the repo - you have to manage those files
   separately